# How to set e.cancel = false to a button in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, controls

How to set `e.cancel = false` to a button e.g `btnInsert`(that clears and enables all field to enter new data) to skip validations that have set e.cancel = true in it???

Comment: @wingedpanther no validation is not set on keyPress but rather than it is done in a function and "Validating" "Validated" Subs, if you want I can provide you the code!

Comment: The eventargs for the click event (I assume) do not have a Cancel property. In fact the event args are the generic `EventArgs` base class.  If you dont want to do something for some reason...dont do it.  If you are talking about some other event...say so but they dont pass values to other events

Comment: @plutonix I just don't want the user to be annoyed of filling a textbox if he choses to do something else for ex: Inserting a new record with btnInsert! Is threre any other way to acheive this, a function or something to call in the btnInsert to set e.cancel to false?

Comment: I understand *what* you want to do but you will have to find another way.  `e.Cancel` is how you communicate back to whatever send the message (like Windows in a Close event).  Your button doesnt know it is an Insert button - it just knows Click and you cant cancel that because it already happened.